# Air pollution plotting in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, air-quality

I want to plot a monthly SO2 concentration for a city day by day in Google Earth Engine. I can visualize on the map by layer but I can't plot a graph.

This is the code I have written:

```
var antalya=turkiye.filterMetadata('NAME_1','equals','Antalya');
Map.addLayer(antalya);

var before_covid_start=('2019-04-01');
var before_covid_end=('2019-04-30');
var after_covid_start=('2020-04-01');
var after_covid_end=('2020-04-30');

var SO2_concentration=ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2')
        .filterBounds(antalya)
        .select('SO2_column_number_density');

var before_SO2 = SO2_concentration.filterDate(before_covid_start,before_covid_end);
var after_SO2 = SO2_concentration.filterDate(after_covid_start, after_covid_end);

var beforeSO2=before_SO2.median().clip(antalya);
var afterSO2=after_SO2.median().clip(antalya);

Map.addLayer(beforeSO2,{
  max:0.0005,
  min:0,
  palette: ['black', 'purple', 'blue', 'green','yellow','orange','red']}, 'SO2 Total - 2019', true,0.6);

Map.addLayer(afterSO2,{
  max:0.0005,
  min:0,
  palette: ['black', 'purple', 'blue', 'green','yellow','orange','red']}, 'SO2 Total - 2020', true,0.6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```
print(ui.Chart.image.series(before_SO2, antalya, ee.Reducer.mean(), 100));
print(ui.Chart.image.series(after_SO2, antalya, ee.Reducer.mean(), 100));
```

Have a look at the [charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/charts_image_series) for Google Earth Engine. You can find more examples there.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. There is an error "invalid JSON".

Comment: I am freshman for the GEE so I can't do smt i want properly.

Comment: That means your antalya feature is not read in properly. Maybe try this: `var antalya=ee.Feature(turkiye.filterMetadata('NAME_1','equals','Antalya'));`

Comment: Ok thanks for it. One more question, how can I export this graph's dataset to my google drive in excel file?

Comment: Maximize the chart from the console. There will then be options to export the data points as csv, which you can open in excel

Comment: Oh I see, thank you!